# How to run a Backbone js app?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am very new to Backbone and MVC frameworks.I am learning backbone.js .
I have followed the tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbonejs-part-1--net-24277

But i have no idea how to run it.I have really looked into many tutorials but i really couldn't find how to run this app!

This might be a very silly question and the solution might be very trivial to some of you,But i have no idea to how to run it!

I have downloaded the attachment http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/1142_bb1/demo.zip
(from the same tutorial) 
Now how do i host it on the server?

Comment: "Now how do i host it on the server?" — You pick some server software, install it and put the files in wherever the software you picked expects them to be. (Or you pay a third party host to provide you with a server set up already)

Comment: @Quentin  Can you please elobarate.I am using Mac OSX Yosemite

Comment: You need a web server. There are many different web servers to choose from. Software recommendation questions are off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if someone is also facing the same issue :

Look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/878025/the-easiest-way-to-serve-a-page-to-localhost-on-os-x)  question.

It tells how to serve a page on mac

In case the link is broken,here is the easiest solution from those answers

> As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server. More details >in the official PHP documentation:
>
> 1.Open terminal.
>
> 2.Navigate to the folder (directory) containing the file you want to serve.
>
> 3.php -S localhost:8080
>
> 4.Go to http://localhost:8080 in the browser.